# Why does blinkLED say it is timing out

Tags: javascript, events, raspberry-pi, event-handling, setinterval

I am having a hard time calling the following function more than once. When I do, I believe I get a timing error and I just can't seem to figure out another way to write this code to enact the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins to execute when given a command. It is mostly ripped from the example and I wrapped it. Any help is appreciated. The function is called in another file.

The code:

```
const GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio
const LED = new GPIO(9, 'out')


function call(){
const blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkLED, 2500);

function blinkLED() { //function to start blinking
  if (LED.readSync() === 0) { //check the pin state, if the state is 0 (or off)
    LED.writeSync(1); //set pin state to 1 (turn LED on)
  } else {
    LED.writeSync(0); //set pin state to 0 (turn LED off)
  }
}

function endBlink() { //function to stop blinking
  clearInterval(blinkInterval); // Stop blink intervals
  LED.writeSync(0); // Turn LED off
  LED.unexport(); // Unexport GPIO to free resources
}

setTimeout(endBlink, 5000);
```

The error:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:298
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:581:3)
    at Gpio.readSync (/home/pi/Documents/project/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:214:8)
    at Timeout.blinkLED [as _onTimeout] (/home/pi/Documents/project/shot.js:10:11)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:551:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:7) {
  errno: -9,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EBADF'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, I think I have figured it out for whoever stumbles across this.

In order to re-use the same pins more than once you need to NOT unexport them according to the on-off NPM package. So without LED.unexport(); the program runs perfectly every time.